# I am getting "Can't install " dialog when trying to install from Play Store

Tags: android

1. I have two flavors: Customer and Driver. Both have different applicationIds(1. com.sample.Driver 
    2.com.sample.customer).
2. I can't install customer if Driver is installed and vice-versa.
3. I just cannot install both on the same device via Google Play. It works fine with apk install.

   build.gradle:

   ```
     productFlavors {
      Customer {  
       applicationId "com.sample.customer"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 26
       versionCode 21
       versionName "3.6"  }
    Driver {  
       applicationId "com.sample.Driver"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 26
       versionCode 20
       versionName "3.6" }    }
   ```

   - Main manifest:

     ```
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     package="com.sample">
     ```
   - Driver manifest:

     ```
     <manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tool"    
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     ```

Comment: Remove applicationId from gradle and add package name in manifest for both. It will work

Answer (score 1):

I did small mistake for package name static(com.pcc.flavors) so getting 
signature issues, after changed applicationId dynamically, it's working fine.

`<permission 
android:name="com.pcc.flavors.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
 android:exported="false"
 android:protectionLevel="signature"/>`

to

`<permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:exported="false" 
android:protectionLevel="signature" 
tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent"/>`